# Why ngModel.valueChanges called when component is initialized in Angular 4 @Directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a directive watching the component changes and calls the custom validators in case of changing of the value.

Why ngModel.valueChanges has a new change when the component is initialized?

```
@Directive({
    providers: [NgModel],
    selector: "[inputValidator][ngModel]",
})
@Inject(BootstrapFormGroupComponent)
export class InputValidatorDirective implements OnInit, BootstrapFormGroupMember {

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.ngModel.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
        // ...
        // calling custom validators
        // why it is called after the component has initialized
        // ...
    });
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="number" inputValidator [validator]="postalCodeValidator" [(ngModel)]="postalCode" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: how do you use it? show html

Comment: what's the initial value of `postalCode`?

Comment: I have tried with null, undefined and ""

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem in angular 6, the only solution I could find was to use skip (1) like this

```
    this.ngModel.valueChanges.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe((value) => {
        // your code here
    });
```